# Why did the first for loop of the code only go through once, and how to improve this code

Tags: python, for-loop

Suppose there is currently a text file named scorel.txt, which stores the computer course grades of students in a certain class, with three columns: student number, usual grade and unexpired grade, and the return of each row of data is separated by spaces. Writing the program is complete:

1. Calculate the overall assessment score (round number) according to the ratio of 40% of the usual grade and 60% of the final grade, and write each student's student number and overall score to another file score2 .txt, and each student's data occupies one row.
2. Output the total number of students in the class on the screen.
3. According to the overall evaluation results, count and output the number of students in each grade bracket above 90, 80~89, 70~79, 60~69, and below 60 points, and output the total average score of the class (1 decimal place is retained)

```py
with open(r"C:\Users\GioGio\Desktop\score1.txt",'r')as f:
    a=[]
    for line in f:
        a.append(line.strip('\n').split('\n'))
    print(a)
    for x in a:
        y=' '.join(x)
        z=y.split(' ')
        keys={'学号','平时成绩','期末成绩'}
        m=dict(zip(keys,z))
        score=0.4*int(m['平时成绩'])+0.6*int(m['期末成绩'])
        p=open(r"score2.txt",'w')
        p.writelines({m["学号"]:score})
        p.close()
    b=len(a)
```

I thought it was the list that caused it to loop only once, and then changed it to a dictionary, but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure what the issue is without seeing the content of the original file and/or seeing the error python is raising.

I suspect that the error is caused by the code `a.append(line.strip('\n').split('\n'))`  is returning a list with only one string in it. The `'\n'` character is the newline character, and I believe that if you're reading a text file this way, there should be no newline characters in the strings of each line because each line is a substring where the substrings are separated by newline characters.

You can use the re.split() method to split a string on an arbitrary number of unknown whitespace characters (e.g. space, tab, and newline) with [regex](http://regexstorm.net/reference).

Something like this

```
from re import split

split(pattern=r'\s+', string='    ssd   sdfsdf          wsf'.strip())
# ['ssd', 'sdfsdf', 'wsf']
```

You don't NEED to use an [r-string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-raw-strings/) for the pattern, but that's how I was taught to do it.